# Django - get_object_or_404 error

Tags: python, django

I'm currently building an app with Django and ran into a problem when doing a `get_object_or_404()` request.

```
object = get_object_or_404(Model,some_field=some_parameter)
```

where `some_parameter = cleaned_data['some_parameter']` in a form. From the values in my DB for `some_field` for each model object, I expected the object to be returned, except that I get a 404.

So then I `print()` out the list of values for the `some_field` field by doing..

```
values = Model.objects.all().values_list('some_field', flat=True)
```

...which returns...

```
<QuerySet [u'value_1', u'value_2', u'value_3']>
```

...where value_2 for example is the `some_parameter` value that I entered in my form!

Anybody know why the object isn't being found even though the parameter I entered in the field actually matches up with one of the object fields?

Thanks

**Edit for clarity:**
Note that the `some_field` field is a `CharField` in both the model and form. And I enter the string into the `CharField` as a normal `input[type='text']` html element.

**Edit with model example:**

```
class Model(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True,unique=True)
```

Also prior to saving this model, I make sure that `some_field` is definitely unique since I compare the field to previous entries and then create a unique one.

Comment: did you try printing `some_parameter = cleaned_data['some_parameter']` before your query?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes, I did, it printed 'value_2' in the terminal, except without the quotation marks

Comment: Make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces and/or newlines in the value.

Comment: what happens if you execute `Model.objects.get(some_field='value_2')` ?

Comment: @delsim It doesn't print anything when I try that

Comment: I should have added something along the lines of print out the response (or error) as it will tell you if you have exactly one object corresponding to some_field, as per the answers others have given.

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` is supposed to return one single object (it's actually only a thin wrapper over `Model.objects.get`) so if more than one record matches your lookup  it will raise a 404 indeed. If you expect more than one single record then it's obviously not the right tool for the job.

Comment: *so if more than one record matches your lookup it will raise a 404 indeed*. I think this part is not correct if more than one matches. Instead, `MultipleObjectsReturned` error will raise, and it will say: `get() returned more than one Model_Name it returned Total_Records!`

Comment: I expect only one record to be returned in my case, and the matching value to the field is in there (as shown by the print of the values_list section: u'value_2'), but it's not matching it for some reason.

Comment: @Lemayzeur `get_object_or_404` raises a `MutlipleObjectsReturned` in this case, indeed - I should have doublechecked. But it's still not the right tool if the lookup can return more than one record ;)

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404()`  returns object, not a query set. If you need the object you have to send the primary key(unique) or any key which uniquely identifies(usally pk)the object.

like - `get_object_or_404(BookModel, pk=some_id)`

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing (see first code line of question). The queryset was just printed there to show that the value is indeed in the set of database objects.

Comment: Can you please edit the code and add the Model and the field which one you are searching. Does the some_field can uniquely identify your object?

Comment: Updated my original question with the model!

Comment: Are you sure objects with this valu exists. Kindly doblecheck in shell or in admin because that should return the object